# Yii2 Gridview checkbox to control attributes disable/enable

Tags: gridview, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I'm in need of your help all.

I get a problem when I want to develop application with yii2.

I've a table and I've create index for my table with GII..


This code in index

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
           'id',
           'name',
           'dob',
           'address',
           'gender',
           'image',
           'contact,
           'passport_no',
           'bank_account',
        // 'id_no',
        // 'mother_name',
        // 'etc',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

if I display all attributes then index view will be very full. So I want to create a view to set which attribute will I display in index. I think I will be select attribute with checkbox, so which attribute is selected that will display in index.

Is there someone who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Add one column in table called visible. Set "Y" or "N" as per your need. 
To achieve this you have to set Visible property conditionally.

```
[
    'label' => 'Bank Account',
    'attribute' => 'bank_account',
    'visible' => function ($data) {
        if ($data->visible == 'Y') {
            return '1'; // or return true; // for visible
        } else {
            return '0'; // or return false; // for hide
        }
    },
],
```

Comment: thank's for your answer @vijay. I've tried, but it's not work for me. What I mean is I want to set/ control what Column in Index to display with checkbox. So We are only select checkbox to control column in index..

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to create a different view in which admins will be able to either turn on or turn off the visibility of some columns. Is this what you want to do or you want an interactive selection system for users and have them select the columns they are interested in via a checkbox list?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I want an interactive selection system for users and have them select the columns they are interested in via a checkbox list. I've add field "visible" in table user to save data column that have been selected by each user. Can you help me? @ravenous